# Software recommendation for creating videos for demoing research results

Tags: software, software-recommendation

I wish to create a video that demonstrates my research results, which comprise of images (graphs, tables, visualisations, etc), image sequences and videos. An example video which achieves what I am trying to do conceptually can be found [here](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/145347/CVPR%202011%20-%20Final%20Video.mp4) (MP4 file, ~15.9 MB).

Therefore, the requirements for my research videos include the ability to create:

1. Title pages
2. Images to be displayed over variable time (e.g. graphs / tables, single frames side-by-side, etc)
3. Text annotations (with options for adding bullet points / numbered lists, arrows, boxes, etc)
4. Video sequences that can be displayed side by side and it is **critical** that they are in sync
5. Image sequences to be played as video with a user-defined frame rate
6. Background audio (voice-overs)

Such resulting video should be of similar quality to the example given and allow good compression ratios.

**OS:** Mac OS X 10.9

**System:** 2.7GHz i7; 16GB RAM

**Budget:** $300 (when justifiable)

**Complexity:** Up to a full day of learning

Given this use case and constraints, what would be the best software tool for such a task?

Comment: Hire someone.  This is exactly what I do for a living.  (I'm not saying you should hire me.  I already have plenty of work on my plate) Engineers and research scientists tend to underestimate the amount of experience and knowledge required to produce quality video.

Comment: Even if all you have to spend is $300 for one project, you can find someone who already has access and experience with the necessary tools to produce your video.

Answer (score 1):

Just about any NLE could handle your needs.  Nothing in that listing seems particular difficult, though with a budget of $300 it might be easiest and fastest to pay an editor to put it together for you really quick.  Alternately, Final Cut Pro X could do it pretty easily since you are on the Mac platform and the most recent copy is just within your budget.

It is a professional NLE (non-linear editor) but there are a ton of tutorials available online to get you going quickly with all the basics and your particular needs are very simple to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting something important: the **time** it will take to learn how to use sophisticated editing software. If this is a one-time task, the previous answerer is right -- hire someone. If you're going to do this regularly, plan on spending at least $300 for Final Cut Pro and a few weeks to learn the basics well.